# Magento 1.9 :- How to add Area value dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I want to add custom text area value when product added to cart
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please follow below code to set custom area value dynamically.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); //error reporting on
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
ob_start();

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$productId = 544;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
/* array(option_id, option_value) */
$options = array('7'=>'4958658');
$paramater = array(
 'product' => $productId,
 'qty' => '1',
 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
    'options' => $options);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
try {
    $cart->save();  
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```